# MYSQL WORKBENCH 5.7, CREATE TABLE FROM QUERY SLOW

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, query-performance

I have always used MS Access and have previously created summary tables(maketable query) using my main data table, ie my main data has all sales information at invoice, I then create a summary table of sales by customer which means I have less rows in that table when viewing by an Intranet page which is far quicker to display.

I have now decided to move over to MYSQL and there is no maketable command, but I can create a table called "customersales" based on a select query.  I have 1 million rows in my main table called "sales".  Doing it this way, it takes 257 seconds to complete this which to me seems very slow. The result actually returns 47000 records into the new table

Below is my create table statement:-

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE 'CREATE_SALESCUSTOMER' ()
BEGIN

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

delete from salescustomer;

```
INSERT
     INTO  SALESCUSTOMER(SumOfNET, SUMOFGROSS, SumOfQTY, SUMOFSQMQUANTITY,
                SUMOFMARGIN, SumOfBUDGETNET,SumOfBUDGETMARGIN,SumOfBUDGETSQM,
                VKORG,VKBURORDER,VKGRPORDER,SALESGROUPORDER,SALESOFFICEORDER,
                CUSTOMER,NAME1,KUNN2,PARTNERNAME,PERDE,GJAHR,SALESDIRECTOR,
                SALESDIRECTORNAME,VKBUR,VKGRP,SALESGROUP,SALESOFFICE,
                STRAS,ORT02,ORT01, COUNTY,PSTLZ,TELF1,konda,kondatext
                        ) 
SELECT  Sum(SALES.NET_SALES) AS SumOfNET,Sum(SALES.NET_SALES) AS SUMOFGROSS,
        Sum(SALES.QTY) AS SumOfQTY,
        Sum(SALES.SUMOFSQMQUANTITY) AS SUMOFSQMQUANTITY,
        Sum(SALES.UKMARGIN) AS SUMOFMARGIN,
        Sum(SALES.BUDGETNET) AS SumOfBUDGETNET,
        Sum(SALES.BUDGETMARGIN) AS SumOfBUDGETMARGIN,
        Sum(SALES.BUDGETSQM) AS SumOfBUDGETSQM,
        SALES.VKORG,SALES.VKBURORDER,
        SALES.VKGRPORDER,SALES.SALESGROUPORDER,
        SALES.SALESOFFICEORDER,SALES.CUSTOMER,SALES.NAME1,SALES.KUNN2,
        SALES.PARTNERNAME,SALES.PERDE,SALES.GJAHR,SALES.SALESDIRECTOR,
        SALES.SALESDIRECTORNAME,SALES.VKBUR,SALES.VKGRP,SALES.SALESGROUP,
        SALES.SALESOFFICE,STRAS,ORT02,ORT01, COUNTY,PSTLZ,TELF1,
        konda,kondatext
    FROM  SALES
    GROUP BY  konda,kondatext,SALES.VKORG,SALES.VKBURORDER,SALES.VKGRPORDER,
        SALES.SALESGROUPORDER,SALES.SALESOFFICEORDER,SALES.CUSTOMER,
        SALES.NAME1,SALES.KUNN2,SALES.PARTNERNAME,SALES.PERDE,
        SALES.GJAHR;
```

Can anyone help, am I doing something wrong, is that speed normal. Sorry, bit of a newbie with MYSQL

thanks
Kevin

Comment: 200K rows per minute is slow, but not outrageously so, for a query with many columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Many things can slow down MySQL queries. You haven't given us enough information to help us do the details of improving your query performance.  Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), and pay attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: **Pro Tip 1:** get your SQL statement to work before putting it into a stored procedure. Stored procedures are harder to debug. **Pro Tip 2:** When you do `INSERT INTO .... SELECT ....` debug the `SELECT` part first. In MySQL you can do `EXPLAIN SELECT` and the query planner will tell you about its logic.

Comment: You can also use any of the multitude of migration applications, e.g. BullZip - http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php

Answer (score 0):

Don't rebuild the Summary table from scratch every time.  Instead *augment* it every day (or week or hour or whatever).  Often this is best done with `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE .. SELECT ...`.  Be sure to have some column so you can "remember where you left off".

This has the side effects of not delivering a full 47K rows each time, and not dropping the table, leaving you without any data briefly.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables